# bootstrap non-stacking column number change as per screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need the `col` classes as they seem to be the only column classes that won't stack?

Basically, I have a form row that needs different number of columns on different screen sizes.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-8"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

On tablets and up, it needs `col-3` & `col-8`. But on phones, it needs `col-2` & `col-9`.

How can I achieve that without overriding these Bootstrap native classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this article to solve your problem.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

`col-*` is used for **Extra small** devices. If you want a different design for your phone you have to use `col-sm-*`

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-3 col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8 col-sm-9"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks! I constantly read that link myself but sometimes I just need to get my head around it.